# Download third party pdf link using HTML and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to download any pdf file. Pdf can be a any third party link.
Currently I can view file in separate tab but need to download automatically.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    
    <a href="http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf" download="http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf">Download me</a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: The download attribute should either be `download` (ie, on its own) or `download="filename.ext"` specifying a new name for the file.

Comment: How can we make this downloadable for third party link?

Comment: pdfs in websites usually are downloadable by default.  Some, however, are done inline - it depends on whether or not they have set the `download` attribute - OR, if the user has selected download as the default action for opening a pdf file.

Comment: If you use Firefox, go to Tools/Options/Applications.  You have a choice of actions available for various file types - the one for pdf defaults to `Preview in Firefox` but you can change that to `Save File`

Answer (score 0):

just check the console of browser and you will see this :

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64247392/download-third-party-pdf-link-using-html-and-javascript' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Of course if you click on link pressing ctrl + click , this will open a new tab and will download the file beacuse is a new request made from browser with a new origin without https.

Peace :)

Comment: How can we make downloadable link or button?

Comment: The only solutions i  think that you have in this case its open the link on new tab  or make  a server route that runs over https then get the file that is over http from server side with a request and returns this file to make downloable

Comment: I don't have access to server. I can access that pdf using link only. And I have to built a page in my other application to download that pdf.